# Read line by line and assign each line to a different variable in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a program that outputs several lines. I want to assign each line to a different variable. I have tried to pipe the output to a block:

```
my_program | {
    read -r foo
    read -r bar
    read -r baz
}
```

It seems that I can only access those variables inside the block but I don't want to put everything inside the block.

I have also tried to use the -d option with a character that is unlikely to show up in the output as it's argument.

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d$'\a' foo bar baz < <(my_program)
```

It seems to work except that if there are more than 3 lines, the variable 'baz' get the third line and all the extra lines. It's not really a problem since I know the exact number of lines that my program is going to output.

I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Any particular reason for not using an array?

Comment: *there are more than 3 lines, the variable 'third' get the third line and all the extra lines* That's how `read` works, yes.

Comment: Maybe `printf "1\n2\n3\n4\n" | { mapfile -t arr;  declare -p arr; }` for example? (just copy and paste to terminal to test) or `mapfile -t arr < <(my_program)` is fine for bash.

Comment: @oguzismail Because I want to refer to them in the subsequent program with decriptive names. Maybe I can use an associative array with the elements of an normal array as keys. Something like ```arr=(first second third); ((cnt = 0)); while read line; do map[${arr[cnt]}]=$line; ((cnt++)); done < <(my_program)```

Comment: @Shawn I know that. I'm just saying that it may not be intended.

Comment: It's intended behavior. See the documentation.

Comment: @Shawn Ah, I didn't get my point clear. Maybe that's because I'm still on my English learning path. I know it's designed that way. I mean it's may not be intended by the programmer. In the first example, three variables get first three lines, while in the second example it's not necessarily so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on that.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

i=0
n=3

while (( i < n )); do
  read -r first
  read -r second
  read -r third
  (( i++ )) || break
done < <(printf '%s\n' one two three four five six)

printf '%s\n' "$first" "$second" "$third"
```

- In your case replace the `printf` with `my_program`
- Also consider using an array like what have suggested in the comments by `@ogus ismail`.

Using `mapfile` aka `readarray`

```sh
mapfile -t -n 3 array < <(printf '%s\n' one two three four five six)
```

The whole `array`

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

Output

```
one
two
three
```

The index starts at zero

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[0]}" "${array[1]}" "${array[2]}"
```

Output

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: The variable names ```first``` and ```second``` in my example are kinda misleading. In my real script, names are something descriptive rather than something correspond to numbers.  I'm considering using associative arrays mentioned in my comment to the question. ```while``` shall do the trick as well. Thanks for that. But I don't get what the point of ```i``` and ```n``` are.  Why not just ```while true; do read -r foo; read -r bar; break; done < <(my_program)```

Comment: You can change the variable as you like. It just feels more readable to me to use a range of numbers, start, end using a counter is all. Of course you can do the `true` and `break`. Since that code snippet comes from my other script that simulates the utility  `head` and `tail`

Comment: I mentioned the variable names to explain why I don't want to use an array. I'm going to mark this as accepted answer to remind me that when I want to do something with pipe I can always do it with ```while``` with the benefit of preserving variables.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. I just realized that I can read lines into an array and then assign each element of the array to a descriptive name.

```sh
mapfile -t arr < <(my_program)
foo=${arr[0]}
bar=${arr[1]}
baz=${arr[2]}
```

I have explained why I don't want to use an array in my comments to the question and the accepted answer. Those variables are actually configuration options so I definitely don't want to refer to `VIRTUAL_IP` with something like `${arr[0]}`.